# Display the count and percentage from result

Tags: php, sql

```
$query = "SELECT TITLE FROM ACCESSLOG ORDER BY TITLE ASC";

$Result = db_query($query);
        while ( $DataResult = $Result->fetchAssoc() ) {
            echo '<a href='. $DataResult["path"].' >'.$DataResult["title"].'</a><br>';
        }
```

It gives the result

Title 1 
Title 1 
Title 1 
Title 1 
Title 2 
Title 2 
Title 2 
Title 3 
Title 3 
Title 4 
Title 5 
Title 5 
Title 5 
Title 5 
Title 6 
Title 6 
Title 6 
Title 7 
Title 8 
Title 8 
Title 9 
Title 9 
Title 9 
Title 10 
Title 10 
Title 10

I need to rewrite it as

Total 26

Title 1 - 4 - 0.2(4/20)
Title 2 - 3 - 0.15(3/20)
Title 3 -  2 - 0.1(2/20)
Title 4 - 1 - 0.05(1/20)
Title 5 - 4 - 0.2(4/20)
Title 6 - 3 - 0.15(3/20)
Title 7 - 1 - 0.1(1/20)
Title 8 - 2 - 0.2(4/20)
Title 9 - 3 - 0.15(3/20)
Title 10 - 3 - 0.15(3/20)

Can it be done by SQL or PHP.

Comment: And what you have tried so far

Comment: Can anyone help me to do in PHP.

Comment: *"Can it be done by SQL or PHP"* --- *"Can anyone help me to do in PHP"* --- you asked for it in SQL, people gave you answers using SQL, so respond to the answers given. Otherwise, modify your question to read as *"Can it be done by PHP"*.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can do:

```
select title, count(*), count(*) * 1.0 / count(*) over ()
from table t
group by title
```

(You can also get the "3 / 20" if you want by putting the columns separately.)

Many PHP users use MySQL, which does not support this syntax.  Instead:

```
select t.title, count(*), count(*) * 1.0 / total.total
from table t cross join
     (select count(*) as total from table t) total
group by t.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.TITLE, COUNT(a.TITLE) AS tot, COUNT(a.TITLE)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCESSLOG b) AS Per 
FROM ACCESSLOG a 
GROUP BY a.TITLE 
ORDER BY a.TITLE ASC
```

Comment: Worked as expected. Modified little bit. SELECT a.TITLE,  COUNT(a.TITLE) AS tot, COUNT(a.TITLE)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCESSLOG b) AS Per
FROM ACCESSLOG a
GROUP BY a.TITLE
ORDER BY a.TITLE ASC

Comment: How can i print the total number of results generated by a query and total number of  distinct titles outside the While loop.

Comment: Matt, the code prints individual count. I need to print results row count (total number of distinct TITLES) and SUM of COUNT(a.TITLE).